# substring position in c

Tags: c, substring

I would like not just to know if the substring exists in a buffer, but to get the position it ends. I am doing a ftp and it will look for @filestart; to start copying the file and only  will return the file when it finds @fileend;
I will send the first message with something like that: @filestart;len=50;
The first part is easy, cause I can use the strstr to find @filestart. But after that I would like to know the end of len, so I can "run" into the buffer, from that position forward until find the equal sign and start copying the lenght until the char ";" or '\0" be found. Sorry for my crap english, I am from Brasil and don't know that good english but I hope you all understand. I made a function to do that, but I would like to know if isn't there a standard one. Here is mine:

```
#define unsigned int B32U
#define char B8

B32U strsub(B8 *data, B8 *key) {
    if (data && key) {
        B8 *d = data;
        B32U len = strlen(key), p = 0;
        if (len > strlen(d))
            return (0);
        while (*d != '\0') {
            if (*(d + len) != '\0') {
                B32U x = 0;
                while (x < len) {
                    if (key[x] == *d) {
                        *d++;
                        p++;
                    } else
                        break;
                    x++;
                }
                if (x == len)
                    return (p);
            } else {
                if (len == 1)
                    if (*d == key[0])
                        return (p);
                B32 x = 0;
                while (x < len) {
                    if (key[x] == *d) {
                        *d++;
                        p++;
                    } else 
                        return (0);
                    x++;
                }
                return (p);
            }
            p++;
            *d++;
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Why not `char *keyloc; if ((keyloc = strstr (data, key))) { /* key exists */ keyloc += strlen(key); /* to find one past end of key in data */ }`??

Comment: *"I would like not just to know if the substring exists in a buffer, but to get the position it ends."* `char *start = strstr(buf, target); char *end = start != NULL ? start + strlen(target) : NULL;`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Note that OP's code handles `NULL` inputs, unlike `strstr()`.

Comment: Precisely -- the proper guards are already there `:)`

Comment: *"The first part is easy, cause I can use the `strstr` to find `@filestart`. But after that I would like to know the end of len, so I can "run" into the buffer, from that position forward until find the equal sign"*. I don't understand. If you can find `@filestart` and you know `len=50` why couldn't you just skip the `len=50` and start reading at that point until you encounter `';'` or `'\0'`?

Comment: MFisherKDX this start variable is just like target. I think if you add the lenght of it, it will get a null as return. You are going to the end of start or target, not to the point from the buf it ends the target. Can you understand what I am trying to say?

Comment: I'm sorry. No, I don't understand. :( Maybe someone else here will.

Comment: David C. Ranking. Cause it should be solving just this problem, I prefer a function, because it is more global, and can aid me in many situations. That funcion is working fine. I prefered doing that, because the user can type @filestart;len = 50; instead of @filestart;len=50; so if I start reading the 50th position as you said and the user type two spaces I will lose some date I think. But if I know the position the len ends, I can skip the buffer from that position until find the equals and start copying the len, avoiding to read wrong things

Comment: I am sorry. Just now I realize the pointer return me all the sentence after target. I guess the solution: char *start = strstr(buf, target); char *end = start != NULL ? start + strlen(target) : NULL; will work.

Comment: with this I remade the function substr, but I think it will be slower the the first version as soon as function take more time to be processed. I mean, to call the function strstr in the function strsub. But the result was the same as my first function..........................................unsigned int strsub2(char * data, char * key){
    char * start = strstr(data,key),* end = start != NULL ? start + strlen(key) : NULL;
    if(data && end){
        return(strlen(data) - strlen(end));
    }
    return(0);
}

Comment: Well,there is `memmem()` , which does not require nul-terminated "strings" HINT: `while (x < len) {...}` prefer for() loops.

Comment: What do you think `#define unsigned int B32U` and `#define char B8` do?

Comment: Also... *I would like not just to know if the substring exists in a buffer, but to get the position it ends*  If you have the substring and you know where it starts in the string you're searching you already know where it ends - because you know how long the substring is.

Answer (score 0):

These defines are really problematic and the code does not compile:

```
#define unsigned int B32U
#define char B8
```

With the above definition, you do not define `B32U` as a preprocessor macro, but `unsigned` and it will expand to `int B32U`, not what you intended.

You should instead use `typedef` to define these types:

```
typedef unsigned int B32U;
typedef char B8;
```

Or not define these types at all and use standard types.

You can use `strstr` to write a simple function that returns a pointer to the end of the match or `NULL` is no match was found:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strstr_end(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char *p = strstr(s1, s2);
    if (p)
        p += strlen(s2);
    return p;
}
```

If you insist on returning the offset from the beginning of the string, you could return a signed type with value `-1` if there is no match and the offset of the end if there is a match. `ptrdiff_t` is an good type for this:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

ptrdiff_t strstr_endpos(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char *p = strstr(s1, s2);
    if (p)
        return p - s1 + strlen(s2);
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with the: #define?

Comment: My codes are working for too long and I always used those types like that.

Comment: Anyway, I will give it a test. I found your strstr_endpos pretty bealtifull. Small and very smart. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

To solve your problem you can use :
    char *strrchr(const char *str, int c)

This function (which is in string.h) will return the adress of the last occurrence of the character c (';' or '\0' in your case) in the string str. However you only can find a char, not a string.

Comment: but how can I know the "int" position from my last occurrence? It will return a char, not an int I guess? My intention is to get the int not the char

Comment: In fatc it will return a char*, wich is a pointer. But you can make arithmetic operation on pointer. And sizeof(char)=1, so just get the result and soustract the initial pointer and you have a int

Comment: I will give it a try and later I'll tell you the result. Thanks for the sugestion

Comment: I don't think this function is gonna be convenient. Because in the last case I read ";", but before that I read "len", so I had to run char by char in order to know the result. And it would not  make much difference between the strsub that I made. If I have to run into a buffer, I prefer to get the final result instead of split it in many process through the strrchr function.